# Scale alpha in ggplot2 depending on number of observations in each facet

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization, alpha-transparency

I am having trouble figuring out how to create an alpha value specific to each facet. Either some of my observations almost disappear (where there are too few values and I set alpha too low) or they form one big blob (where there are lots of values and I set alpha too high).

Dummy example with `diamonds`:

```
library(tidyverse)
ggplot(data = diamonds,
       mapping = aes(x = price, y = carat)) +
  geom_point(alpha = 0.1) +
  facet_grid(cut ~ clarity) +
  scale_alpha_continuous(range = c(0,1))
```

[image]

... works alright where there are lots of values, but difficult to pick out anything in top right facet... an alternative:

```
ggplot(data = diamonds,
       mapping = aes(x = price, y = carat)) +
  geom_point(alpha = 0.1) +
  facet_grid(cut ~ clarity) +
  scale_alpha_continuous(range = c(0,1))
```

[image]

...easier to pick up points in top right facet but the more populated combinations have become more of a solid blurb.

I want to somehow set the alpha based on the number of observations:

```
d0 <- diamonds %>% 
   group_by(cut, clarity) %>%
   summarise(n = n())
d0
# A tibble: 40 x 3
# Groups:   cut [?]
     cut clarity     n
   <ord>   <ord> <int>
 1  Fair      I1   210
 2  Fair     SI2   466
 3  Fair     SI1   408
 4  Fair     VS2   261
 5  Fair     VS1   170
 6  Fair    VVS2    69
 7  Fair    VVS1    17
 8  Fair      IF     9
 9  Good      I1    96
10  Good     SI2  1081
# ... with 30 more rows
```

But I am stuck when it comes to how to implement this... my attempts seem to break something for the more populated combinations...

```
ggplot(data = diamonds %>%
         group_by(cut, clarity) %>%
         mutate(n = n()),
       mapping = aes(x = price, y = carat, alpha = 1/n)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_grid(cut ~ clarity) +
  scale_alpha_continuous(range = c(0,1))
```

[image]

Note: I am not too sure this type of facet scaling of the alpha makes complete sense with this dummy data, but I have good justification to do this with my actual (weighted) data that I am trying to visualize.

Comment: Mayby try `diamonds %>% add_count(cut, clarity) %>% mutate(alpha = scales::rescale(n, c(.2, .01)))` ... and then `+ geom_point(aes(alpha = I(alpha)))`.

Comment: If you did set a different alpha scale for each facet, then you plot would be misleading. Maybe try `stat_bin_hex` with a `geom_smooth` overlay.

Comment: @Gregor I was using some dummy data... see the last sentence

Comment: @Gregor I don't think it would be misleading. With the scale removed, I see this objective (why I wanted to do this, anyway) as allowing the viewer to see the density/clusters of points. With a non-ideal alpha, it's too saturated (just looks black) or is barely visible. I see the alpha scaled to different numbers to consistently let the viewer understand where the various % of the data lies, indicated by per-group "darkness".

Comment: Currently not answered either, but linking this question as it's basically the same: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42433116/independent-alpha-for-each-plot-within-facet-grid-based-on-density

Comment: @Hendy Misleading is in the eye of the beholder - and hard to judge without seeing the context and actual data. Perhaps "would be misleading" is too strong, and "might be misleading" is better - but if a particular dark value means "10 points are here" on facet X "100 points are here" on facet Y, with no way to tell the difference, that could be misleading.

Comment: @Gregor fair point. In my use case, I'm removing the scale so really just looking to convey density, and too low = invisible and too high = saturated to black. Viewed as quantifying the data, I think it would mislead; viewed as qualitatively showing where the data is clustered (my use case), I don't think it is.